# debian internal-sftp -u 0002 umask does not work correctly - execute permission missing

Tags: ssh, permissions, sftp, umask

I've been searching here and but I could not find similar question.

I have set up `SSH` and `sftp` server on `debian 7`, the problem is that the `umask` is applied without execute permissions. Even if I change the different value, execute permissions are never applied.

Here is my configuration:

```
Match Group sftp-users  
    ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
    AuthorizedKeysFile  /sftp/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys   
    X11Forwarding no 
    AllowTcpForwarding no 
    # AuthenticationMethods    publickey 
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0002
```

Example:

- `-u 0002` uploaded file.txt should get 775 permissions but gets 664 instead
- `-u 0222` uploaded file.txt should get 555 but got 444
- `-u 0666` uploaded file.txt should get 111 but got 000

Could you please let me know which files should be checked or what other config you need to see?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should understand what is the [`umask`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html) (manual page explains it quite well). It is not a complete negation of the permissions you will get, but a mask of permissions that should get stripped from the original permissions of the uploaded file. This means, that you need to take into the account the original permission of the file you are trying to upload, which is generally `0666`, unless it is executable file (but you can never know what permissions will have the files users are going to upload).

This is why there is a [bug in upstream OpenSSH](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1844) to request a functionality as you describe, but it is certainly not called `umask` anymore. If you want to use this functionality, it is already in Fedora/RHEL.

Comment: Thank you, this explanation was very helpful for me! it summarized my assumptions.